# Help with Janrain Engage openID C# code behind for asp.net forms website

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, janrain

I have signed up with Janrain Engage to incorporate its free widget based openID. But i can't figure out what values to put in the C# code behind. They have provided with a C# helper class, the one below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
public class Rpx
{
    private string apiKey;
    private string baseUrl;
    public Rpx(string apiKey, string baseUrl) {
        while (baseUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            baseUrl = baseUrl.Substring(0, baseUrl.Length - 1);
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }
    public string getApiKey() { return apiKey; }
    public string getBaseUrl() { return baseUrl; }
    public XmlElement AuthInfo(string token) {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        query.Add("token", token);
        return ApiCall("auth_info", query);
    }
    public List<string> Mappings(string primaryKey) {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        query.Add("primaryKey", primaryKey);
        XmlElement rsp = ApiCall("mappings", query);
        XmlElement oids = (XmlElement)rsp.FirstChild;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < oids.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
            result.Add(oids.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public Dictionary<string,ArrayList> AllMappings() {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        XmlElement rsp = ApiCall("all_mappings", query);
        Dictionary<string,ArrayList> result = new Dictionary<string,ArrayList>();
        XPathNavigator nav = rsp.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator mappings = (XPathNodeIterator) nav.Evaluate("/rsp/mappings/mapping");
        foreach (XPathNavigator m in mappings) {
            string remote_key = GetContents("./primaryKey/text()", m);
            XPathNodeIterator ident_nodes = (XPathNodeIterator) m.Evaluate("./identifiers/identifier");
            ArrayList identifiers = new ArrayList();
            foreach (XPathNavigator i in ident_nodes) {
                identifiers.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            result.Add(remote_key, identifiers);
        }
        return result;
    }
    private string GetContents(string xpath_expr, XPathNavigator nav) {
        XPathNodeIterator rk_nodes = (XPathNodeIterator) nav.Evaluate(xpath_expr);
        while (rk_nodes.MoveNext()) {
            return rk_nodes.Current.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void Map(string identifier, string primaryKey) {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        query.Add("identifier", identifier);
        query.Add("primaryKey", primaryKey);
        ApiCall("map", query);
    }
    public void Unmap(string identifier, string primaryKey) {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        query.Add("identifier", identifier);
        query.Add("primaryKey", primaryKey);
        ApiCall("unmap", query);
    }
    private XmlElement ApiCall(string methodName, Dictionary<string,string> partialQuery) {
        Dictionary<string,string> query = new Dictionary<string,string>(partialQuery);
        query.Add("format", "xml");
        query.Add("apiKey", apiKey);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> e in query) {
            if (sb.Length > 0) {
                sb.Append('&');
            }
            sb.Append(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Key, Encoding.UTF8));
            sb.Append('=');
            sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Value, Encoding.UTF8));
        }
        string data = sb.ToString();
        Uri url = new Uri(baseUrl + "/api/v2/" + methodName);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        // Write the request
        StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(),
                                              Encoding.ASCII);
        stOut.Write(data);
        stOut.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        doc.Load(dataStream);
        XmlElement resp = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (resp == null || !resp.GetAttribute("stat").Equals("ok")) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected API error");
        }
        return resp;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Rpx r = new Rpx(args[0], args[1]);
        if (args[2].Equals("mappings")) {
            Console.WriteLine("Mappings for " + args[3] + ":");
            foreach(string s in r.Mappings(args[3])) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        if (args[2].Equals("all_mappings")) {
            Console.WriteLine("All mappings:");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList> pair in r.AllMappings()) {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ":");
                foreach (string identifier in pair.Value) {
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + identifier);
                }
            }
        }
        if (args[2].Equals("map")) {
            Console.WriteLine(args[3] + " mapped to " + args[4]);
            r.Map(args[3], args[4]);
        }
        if (args[2].Equals("unmap")) {
            Console.WriteLine(args[3] + " unmapped from " + args[4]);
            r.Unmap(args[3], args[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me but i'm not a master of C#, but i can't figure out where to put the values for the apiKey and the token_url. Also if a user signs in how to display the username as derived from the accounts he is using to sign up, Google or Yahoo! for example.
Also there is no sign out option provided.
Any help would be much appreciated as the Janrain developer help is nothing but useless.

Answer (score 2):

I agree the JanRain does not make this very clear.  You do not need to modify the Rpx helper example code provided.   Here is some code that makes use of their Rpx helper class from an MVC application.  Be sure to include System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq.

```
var token = Request.Form["token"];
var rpx = new Helpers.Rpx("your-api-key-goes-here", "https://rpxnow.com");
var authInfo = rpx.AuthInfo(token);
var doc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(authInfo));                
ViewData["displayName"] = doc.Root.Descendants("displayName").First().Value;
ViewData["identifier"] = doc.Root.Descendants("identifier").First().Value;
```